# How do I use regular expressions in ternary statements / keymappings?

Tags: key-bindings, regular-expression, filetype

I'd like to create a keymapping with a conditional statement, so that it behaves differently when a given line is blank.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370260/) gave me the following snippet, which is great – except that it doesn't match lines that are blank-except-for-a-comment-marker. I'd like to capture those lines, too.

`inoremap <expr> [KEY SEQUENCE] getline(line(".")+1) =~ "^$" ? "[COMMAND]" : "[COMMAND]"`

So I set out to build a regular expression. `'\v^(#|"|*)?$'` is what I came up with. I tested it in vim's command line, and it looks like it should work:

`:echo getline(line(".")) =~ '\v^(#|"|*)?$'`

returns `1` on the target lines, and returns `0` on all others.

But then the same expression used in the following mapping throws an error:

`nnoremap <expr> <Leader>o (getline(line(".")) =~ '\v^(#|"|*)?$') ? (":echo '1'") : (":echo '0'")`

gives

```
E115: Missing quote: '\v^(#
E15: Invalid expression: (getline(line(".")) =~ '\v^(#`
```

Then I tried rewriting the regular expression without the `\v` flag: `'^\(\#\|\"\|\*\)\?$'`. It still works in command-line testing, and eliminates the error, but still doesn't match as expected. (It matches blank lines, but not those beginning with a comment marker.)

What am I missing? (Additionally, does Vimscript have a way to specify "current-filetype's-comment-marker", so I don't have to lump all three of these together as one?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The parentheses are unnecessary.
2. The error is caused by the unescaped pipes in your pattern. Escape them to fix that error:

   ```
   nnoremap <expr> <key> getline(line(".")) =~ '\v^(#\|"\|*)?$' ? ":echo 1\<CR>" : ":echo 0\<CR>"
   ```

> Additionally, does Vimscript have a way to specify "current-filetype's-comment-marker", so I don't have to lump all three of these together as one?

Yes, you can use `&commentstring` but it may or may not be correctly set for *every* filetype.

Comment: you can define `&commentstring` in a `ftplugin` for the filetypes missing!

Comment: THANK YOU, I'd been futzing around all day with that nonsense. Now a follow-up question: When I replace `(#\|"\|*)` with `(&commentstring)`, I get a `could not pop the stack!` error. Do you know the appropriate syntax offhand? (or... can vim regular expressions interpolate variables at all?)

Comment: `'(' . &commentstring . ')'`